# Are backlinks transitive when old URL is forwarded to new URL?

Tags: url, 301-redirect, backlinks

Say there are two companies operating in the same industry: `www.companya.com` and `www.companyb.com`. Company A has acquired some backlinks over time.

Company B acquires company A and decides to only use its URL. It forwards properly all links from `www.companya.com` to `www.companyb.com`.

Will company B benefit from the backlinks of `www.companya.com` through the redirection? Is it worth the effort from a backlink perspective only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 301 redirects are made, the `www.companyb.com` website benefits from the backlinks of `www.companya.com`.
However, you lose a little bit PageRank (so a little bit benefit) through the 301 redirect.

And indeed, from backlinks perspective, it's worth your while to implement 301 redirects. It's even recommended for backlinks and users.